# Enable UWF via WMI

Tags: wmi, c#-2.0, uwf, uwfmgr

I am writing a program that needs to enable UWF. Unfortunately, I have no experience with the WMI interface and the UWF documentation has no C# or .NET examples.

When I enable UWF, I get an exception: 'Invalid method Parameters(s)'. But, according to the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-filter - Enable does not have input parameters. Passing through null doesn't work neither:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
var uwfClass = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_Filter", null);
var inputParameters = uwfClass.GetMethodParameters("Enable");
var result = uwfClass.InvokeMethod("Enable", inputParameters, null);
```

Comment: Have you tried just calling `uwfClass.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);` - without the `inputParameters`?

Comment: Yes I have, I should have mentioned that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of headache, I finally know why it didn't work. The ManagementClass only represents a class, not the object (instance). To make it work, I need to invoke the method on the instance:

```
var instances = uwfClass.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject instance in instances)
{
    var result = instance.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
    break; //There should only be one instance, but to be sure, exit after first instance
}
```

It might be logical, but not very obvious if you are not used to WMI.

Comment: I know my answer is a bit late ;-): I created a small C# application some time ago (open source under MIT license), in which I enable and disable the UW filter via CIM (WMI), among other things. Maybe it helps someone...